# Как удалить из http заголовка x-frame options?

Tags: http, drupal, cgi

Система управления Drupal 7

Средствами дурпала этот заговлок не удаляется так как на сайте включен кеш, соответственно и не выполняются функции во время получения страницы

нашел что можно удалить через htacces
Header unset X-Frame-Options

но этот файл выполняется на серверах под апачем а у меня на сервере используется CGI

может быть тоже есть какой то файл, который можно создать и выполнить из папки с сайтом, или может на сервере можно задать такую настройку. если да то куда копать?